# SSRS reports does not show all the data in view

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

SSRS report does not pull all the data from the view that its bind to. This view when run sql server shows more than 250 records but when this same view is integrated with SSRS report it shows very few of them less than 10 records. It does not have any parameters as such. Its just a report to display the available time on each day for the resources. Is there anything that I am missing.

Here is SQL query:

```
SELECT C_code, Eq_Code, header, quantity, date
FROM    V_available_hours
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime2(0), date) IN (@date))
```

Comment: Please show your SQL in the question. Can't help without it

Comment: @PaulBambury updated my question...

Comment: Have you tried hitting the refresh button or deleting the .data file?  It might be a caching issue.

Comment: Ah, so the query is parameterised... How's the value of @date getting set?

Comment: @JoeC yes i tried deleting the data file

Comment: @PaulBambury you mean the format of the date?

Comment: Yes, what is the format of `@date` and how is that being provided to the view? Date picker?

Comment: @WEI_DBA not a date picker, I created a parameter for this date on the report and its in this format '12/20/2016 12:57:00 PM'

Comment: I get the results on the query designer when i pass the date parameter but when see on the preview of the report it does not show all data.

Comment: So it's declared as a `datetime2` format?

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes its datetime2

Comment: Can you show the code that you are running in the SSRS preview?

Comment: @WEI_DBA got to fix this its because of the row group properties that i was not getting the complete data. Added a row group and got all the date.. thanks all